# PyGObject: How do widgets maintain references to signal handlers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

I was trying to find the root cause of a bug in my app and managed to end up with an MCVE that I did not understand (included later).

My train of thought was this:

```
import gc, gi, weakref
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

widget = Gtk.Window()
widget.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
widget.connect('draw', lambda *args: print('draw'))
widget.show()

widget_wr = weakref.ref(widget)
del widget
gc.collect()

print('widget_wr() -> {!r}'.format(widget_wr()))  # prints: `widget_wr() -> None`

Gtk.main()
```

In the above code, even though `widget` has been garbage collected (I'm guessing since `widget_wr()` is None), the window widget is still visible, resizing it (causing it to emit `draw` signals) spams `draw` in the console, and closing the window quits the main loop.

So in my MCVE, I was basically trying to check if `widget.connect(..., my_callback)` would somehow create a strong reference to `my_callback`, preventing `my_callback` from being garbage collected for at least as long as the window widget was visible on the user's screen and available for interaction, despite `widget` having already been (again I'm guessing) garbage collected.

This is the MCVE I ended up with:

```
import gc, gi, sys, weakref
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, widget, store_widget):
        self.x = 123
        if store_widget:
            self.widget = widget

    def method(self, *args):
        print("getattr(self, 'x', default='nothing') -> {!r}"
              .format(getattr(self, 'x', 'nothing')))


widget = Gtk.Window()
obj = MyObject(widget, store_widget=True)  # or try store_widget=False

weakref.finalize(widget, print, 'widget finalize')
weakref.finalize(obj, print, 'obj finalize')

widget.connect('draw', obj.method)
widget.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
widget.show()

obj_wr = weakref.ref(obj)
widget_wr = weakref.ref(widget)

del obj
del widget

print('Garbage collecting...')
gc.collect()
print('Garbage collected.')

print('obj_wr() -> {}, widget_wr() -> {}'.format(obj_wr(), widget_wr()))

if obj_wr() is not None:
    print('sys.getrefcount(obj_wr()) -> {}, gc.get_referrers(obj_wr()) -> {}'
          .format(sys.getrefcount(obj_wr()), gc.get_referrers(obj_wr())))

Gtk.main()
```

When I run the above as-is, the output I get is:

```
Garbage collecting...
widget finalize
obj finalize
Garbage collected.
obj_wr() -> None, widget_wr() -> None
getattr(self, 'x', default='nothing') -> 'nothing'
getattr(self, 'x', default='nothing') -> 'nothing'
... <and so on as the window is resized>
```

So I concluded that maybe `widget.connect(..., my_callback)` wouldn't somehow indirectly create a strong reference to `my_callback`, but still I felt it was weird that `obj.method()` was still being called whenever the window was resized, despite `obj` having been garbage collected.

Then, (as I was creating the MCVE), I modified the code such that `widget` wouldn't be kept as an attribute of `obj`, this change is reflected by the following modification to the above MCVE:

```
obj = MyObject(widget, store_widget=False)
```

And the output I then get is:

```
widget finalize
Garbage collecting...
Garbage collected.
obj_wr() -> <__main__.MyObject object at 0x10f478208>, widget_wr() -> None
sys.getrefcount(obj_wr()) -> 2, gc.get_referrers(obj_wr()) -> [<bound method MyObject.method of <__main__.MyObject object at 0x10f478208>>]
getattr(self, 'x', default='nothing') -> 123
getattr(self, 'x', default='nothing') -> 123
... <and so on>
```

This time, somehow `obj` is prevented from being garbage collected.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on? And also, another question is if I should be maintaining some reference to every widget to prevent them from being gc'd, or is it okay to just 'create-and-forget' like the very first example.

Thanks for reading this.

---

**Edit:**

Tried another variation, modified the initializer of `MyObject` class to this:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, widget, store_widget):
        self.x = 123
        self.widget = widget
        widget.__my_obj_ref = self  # store a reference to self in widget
    ...
```

And added this to the end, just before `Gtk.main()`:

```
print('sys.getrefcount(widget_wr()) -> {}, gc.get_referrers(widget_wr()) -> {}'
      .format(sys.getrefcount(widget_wr()), gc.get_referrers(widget_wr())))
```

Output:

```
Garbage collecting...
Garbage collected.
obj_wr() -> <__main__.MyObject object at 0x10ab55208>, widget_wr() -> <Gtk.Window object at 0x10ba600d8 (GtkWindow at 0x7fb81b00a280)>
sys.getrefcount(obj_wr()) -> 3, gc.get_referrers(obj_wr()) -> [{'_MyObject__my_obj_ref': <__main__.MyObject object at 0x10ab55208>}, <bound method MyObject.method of <__main__.MyObject object at 0x10ab55208>>]
sys.getrefcount(widget_wr()) -> 3, gc.get_referrers(widget_wr()) -> [{'widget': <Gtk.Window object at 0x10ba600d8 (GtkWindow at 0x7fb81b00a280)>, 'x': 123}]
getattr(self, 'x', default='nothing') -> 123
getattr(self, 'x', default='nothing') -> 123
...
```

This time both `obj` and `widget` are prevented from being garbage collected.

Comment: Don't know the answer and I had strange things happen when testing things like this. Like (when running scripts through IDLE) I tried calling `Gtk.main_quit` (without `destroy`ing any widgets) with a button and the program ended. But the window was still there. It didn't respond until I moved it. Then it was kind of usable (you could do something and it would be non responsive until yo moved it again). Anyway, I had another button connected to a function that just printed to the console and it still worked.

Comment: It's very strange behaviour. Are you sure that Gtk.main() is not called in a loop?

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev ? I didn't quite get that. I think it's just getting called once at the end and not multiple times, creating some kind of event loop in an event loop

Comment: I'm asking about widgets *not* disappearing after `Gtk.main_quit()`. It stops the event loop and it's not possible to draw anything else unless you run it again

Comment: @AlexanderDmitriev Oh ok, was that question meant for Daniel F. or in relation to this post?

Comment: about your question: I don't know the answer, but it looks like some sort of UB. Like the object is deleted, but this exact part of memory is not overridden. Gtk calls `method` which is still available (I suppose, that it's not possible to delete whole class in python)  and passes `obj` to it implicitly, but `obj` is deleted already and python won't let to read 'x'.

Comment: @eugenhu oh, yes. My bad, thought it was part of the question.

Comment: There's more to add to my previous answer. You can take a look at GSignal source code e.g. [here](https://github.com/bratsche/glib/blob/master/gobject/gsignal.c#L2267) and notice that it [stores](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gobject/gclosure.c#L944) pointer to `callback` and `userdata`. If you pass a list and then change it, it will be passed to handler in actual (changed) state. This makes me think, that my comment is not far from truth. Two pointers are passed: `obj.method` and NULL (as you don't provide any `user_data`